# Split a string into array from back

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers

I have a string.

```
var string = "31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164";
```

I want to split it into an array of length 10 from back.

I have:

```
function split(a) {
  return a.split( /(?=(?:..........)*$)/ ).map(function(x){return parseInt(x)});
}
```

which gives me the desired output as:

```
[3, 1415926535, 8979323846, 2643383279, 5028841971, 6939937510, 5820974944, 5923078164]
```

**Questions:**

- How do I make the above function dynamic so I can break strings to n number of characters? (Currently I am adding/removing dots)
- How do I skip the first character when splitting? (I would like first element to be always 3 so second element can be of length 1 to n)?

Comment: Instead of `?:..........`, do `?:.{10}`.

Comment: Why would you overcomplicate some simple operations on string split by index into some compilcated regex?

Comment: @texasbruce what would be the simple way of doing it?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I tried having a variable like {n} but it didnot work. I found out we cant really pass variables in regex without using RegExp constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just specify the number of digits you want to get for each item inside curly braces. And note that you can't pass variable to the regex which uses `/` as delimiters. You have to use `RegExp` constructor to pass variables in regex.

```js
var string = "31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164";
function split(a,n) {
  return a.split( new RegExp("(?=(?:.{" + n + "})*$)" )).map(function(x){return parseInt(x)});
}
alert(split(string, 10))
```

OR

You may simply use match instead of split.

```
string.match(/(?!^.).{11}/gm)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dO0mM8/3)

```js
var string = "31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164";
function split(a,n) {
  return a.match(new RegExp("(?!^.).{" + n + "}|^.", "gm")).map(function(x){return parseInt(x)});
}
alert(split(string, 11))
```

If you also want to match the remaining chars, ie, the char present at the start and the unmatched chars exists at the last, you may use this regex.

```
/(?!^.).{11}|^.|.+/gm
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dO0mM8/4)

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Great solution. In my jsfiddle I've wrapped it up in a helper function. http://jsfiddle.net/kieranpotts/8wjszvc5/1/

Comment: Perfect. Thank you Avinash. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

the easy way..without using RegExp
    var string="31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164";
    var arr = new Array();
    while (!string.length < 10) {
        substr = string.substr(strlen(string)-10);
        string = string.replace(substr, '');
        arr.push(substr);
    }
    var result_arr = arr.reverse();

Comment: This is PHP rather than JavaScript. But if you could convert this to JS @Aniket, this would be the better answer probably, since it does not rely on regexes. What do you think? :)

Comment: Thank you Aniket. jsperf is down at this time. I will do some performance testing with all the solutions when its back up.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

```
var _mySplit = function(str, splitLength) {
    var _regEx = '';
    var startSubStringLength = str.length % splitLength
    if(startSubStringLength > 0) {
        _regEx = new RegExp("(^.{1," + startSubStringLength + "})|(.{1," + splitLength +  "})|(.{1,})", "g")
    }
    return str.match(_regEx)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Harpeet. I will do some performance testing later with and without regex when jsperf is back up.